# javascript grammar: function

Tags: javascript

I found the source code like this.
I am familiar with javascript anonymous function though,

what is `:`?

For example

When I call `createOverlays` function with argument, how can I make it ?

I am googling around about `:` but unable to find good explanation.

I might not understand the basic javascript structure.

Please give some hint.

```
var World = {
    init: function initFn() {   
        this.createOverlays();
    },

    createOverlays: function createOverlaysFn() {
         // some function
    },
}
```

---

simply solved.
I can pass the argument like this.

```
var World = {
    init: function initFn() {   
        this.createOverlays(1);
    },
    createOverlays: function createOverlaysFn(arg) {
         // some function
         console.log(arg) //show 1
    },
}
```

Comment: Haven't you heard about [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Instead of Googling, just read some basic JS tutorials. What does "archive" mean?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I found I can pass the argument like this. I should learn more about Object. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `:` in this case creates a property on the object `World`.  So the property `createOverlays` is being set to the function following it.

If you want to access it, you need to access the object first, and use the dot or bracket notation to access it:

```
// Dot Notation
World.createOverlays();

// Bracket Notation
World['createOverlays']();
```

Comment: Hi it also a nice suggestion. it's a little bit different from what I asked though, thanks very much.